# How to translate exception titles in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, translation, yii2

My Yii 2 application (based on *app-basic* scheme) still display English titles for exceptions like for example `NotFoundHttpException`, when user switches site language to non-English. Any other page element is correctly translated. Where titles of exceptions are stored? How can I fix this problem?

I tried searching through exception classes (`NotFoundHttpException` > `HttpException` > `UserException` > `Exception`) and found nothing. I browsed based translation files and found that `/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/` files have only `The requested view "{name}" was not found.` and `Page not found.` string for translations. There is no `Not Found` or `Not Found (` strings to make correct translation of `NotFoundHttpException` (and others) exception's title in non-English languages.

Related readings:

- [Yii2 Forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/64615-how-to-translate-exception-titles-in-yii-2/page__view__findpost__p__283360),
- [Yii2 GitHub issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8931#issue-91730833).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no build-in translation of error or status code messages.  One could implement a custom `ErrorAction` to translate the HTTP response codes.
The documentation of [`yii\web\ErrorAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html) has the details of how to proceed.

An alternative solution would be to use custom `HttpException`s and overwrite the `getName` function, but this would require you replicate all error classes you want to use.

Example:

*Translation trait:*

```
namespace app\errors;

use Yii;

trait TranslateHttpCodes {
    public function getName()
    {
        return Yii::t('app', parent::getName());
    }
}
```

*Custom error*:

```
namespace app\error;

class NotFoundHttpException extends \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
{
   use TranslateHttpCodes;
}
```

As for error messages, the Yii error constructors take a message as an optional argument, so the message can be chosen freely.

What this means is that one would have to put something like the following in the `findModel` controller method.

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException(\Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.');
```

The `gii` code generator doesn't do this automatically, even though it offers an `--enableI18N` command line flag.  This might be considered a bug.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same code, like you showed, to translate **body** (message on error screen). I don't understand, how this would help me translating `Not Found` part, that is -- **title** of error screen. Either I don't drunk enough coffee today or I get the feeling, that your answer is off-topic. You're talking all the way down about message, while I'm asking about title.

Comment: It's definitely me who didn't have enough coffee.

Comment: Updated my answer to give a better (on topic) solution.